# ArgumentError when trying to save multiple records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

## What we want to achieve

I am sending an array from Nuxt.js, Rails is in API mode and I am getting an error when I try to retrieve and save the array contents one by one.
I want to save the array received by params and add multiple records.

## Error

```
ArgumentError (When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument, Array passed.):
```

## Code

**Controller**

```rb
def create
      schedule = Schedule.new(post_params)
      if schedule.save
        render json: schedule,  status: :created
      else
        render json: schedule, status: :internal_server_error
    end
  end


def post_params
      params.require(:post).map do |schedule|
        schedule.permit(:id, :name, :start, :end, :color, :timed, :long_time, :post_id, :post_item_id)
      end
    end
```

**parameter**

```
post: [,…]
0: {name: "", color: "#2196F3", start: 1648275300000, end: 1648276200000, timed: true, long_time: true}
1: {name: "", color: "#2196F3", start: 1648361700000, end: 1648362600000, timed: true, long_time: true}
2: {name: "", color: "#2196F3", start: 1648448100000, end: 1648449000000, timed: true, long_time: true}
3: {name: "", color: "#2196F3", start: 1648534500000, end: 1648535400000, timed: true, long_time: true}
4: {name: "", color: "#2196F3", start: 1648620900000, end: 1648621800000, timed: true, long_time: true}
```

## What we tried

・I tried to retrieve a value using map.

・I tried to convert it to a hash using to_h at the end of pemit, but neither the value nor the error changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first question here is what is happening if one of the records failed, do previously created should be rollbacked and following actions to be aborted or you just ignore invalid creations.

In case of rollback/aborting you can go for `Schedule.create!(post_params)` - responding with the proper message error and all others will be rollbacked.

In case of ignoring failure ones, go for `Schedule.create!(post_params)` - responding with created and failure ones.